# Marathon24 contest quals: DNA -TLE

Tags: algorithm

I'm re-attempting this [problem statement](http://www.marathon24.com/static/attachment/marathon24_dna_en.pdf), [now that the contest is all over](http://www.marathon24.com/news/) (so it's not cheating or anything, just want to learn, since the answers are not published, only the correct output for the given test case input files).

There are 10 given test case inputs, for which the associated output files are to be submitted. My original submission was an implementation of a naive nested for loop of (start,end) pairs, answering the query: What is the volatility measure of the substring starting at (0-based) index `start`, and ending at `end` (inclusive).

Clearly, for the maximum problem limits of 10<sup>6</sup>, O(N<sup>2</sup>) is infeasible, so I only got as far as 5/10 test cases correct (the first - and simpler - 5, of course).

As such, I'm writing here to seek the crowd intelligence on how I could go about improving my algorithm, namely I suspect the nested for loops (start,end) is the main bottleneck to optimize (of course!) So far, I've gone down the route of trying to formulate this as a dynamic programming (DP) on strings/substrings problem, but without any much success on coming up with the state representation and transition bits so that the DP can be implemented.

For easy reference, and to show that this is not homework, and I have honestly tried, my original submission is available [here](http://codepad.org/K0V8GfTs).

Any help is much appreciated, even links to similar problems for which I can google for tutorial blog posts/sample solutions/post-contest editorial analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried divide-and-conquer?

If I understand the problem correctly, given a DNA chain S of length n, we divide S into two halves, S_left and S_right, with S_left consisting of S[i] where 0 <= i < n/2, and S_right consisting of S[j] where (n/2)+1 <= j < n. The most volatile fragment either occurs entirely within S_left, entirely within S_right, or crosses the boundary of S_left and S_right.

To find the most volatile fragment of S_left and S_right we just use recursion. THe tricky bit is to find the volatility measure of the fragment which crosses the boundary of S_left and S_right. There is a mathematical property of positive integer fraction here: *given four positive (non-zero) integers a, b, c and d, (a + c) / (b + d) is never greater than both (a / b) and (c / d)*. Here *a* and *b* are the cumulative count of purines and pyrimidines in S_left starting at the boundary, while *c* and *d* are the cumulative count of purines and pyrimidines in S_right starting at the boundary. This mathematical property means that we don't need to examine the volatility measure of the crossing fragment beyond a = 0 or c = 0 because it is guaranteed to be less than the maximum volatility of S_left or S_right. The time complexity of such search can be done in O(n) for the crossing fragment, and O(n lg n) for the overall algorithm.

Hope this works as I haven't coded the algorithm. Perhaps it has a O(n) time DP algorithm for this problem but this is all I've got for now.

Comment: Thanks, will try it soon when I next get the chance to. I'll attach comments received from my similar post elsewhere, eg. Codeforces, Codechef, Topcoder etc. for your reference and information

Comment: #1: testcase data is special, the number of 'T' or 'C' on every case is small
and can be bruteforced, except one case which contain 1000000 'T' or 'C'
character and no 'A' or 'G' character which obviously can be solved by hand.

Comment: #2: 1. If we want to maximize only the ratio, not the length, we can consider
substrings with only one bad letter.

2. If length is also taken into cosideration, we should additionally check if
there exists a substring of form 0000110000 (k zeros, 2 ones and k zeros),
where k is the best ratio.

P.S. At the beginning the ratio of T's and C's to the A's and G's was near 1.
Later, in order to make inputs better compress, this ratio were highly
lowered.